# is it possible to create 16M + combinations in excel?

Tags: python, excel, colors, hex, combinations

if I want to create an excel document with all the possible combinations of hex color codes( 16,772,216) is it possible?
or is there another program that can help me with that?

thanks

Comment: A Microsoft Excel document has the following row/column limits: 1,048,576 / 16,384. So, yes, you can fit all of those values in an Excel spreadsheet

Comment: thanks. maybe you know how can I calculate all these combinations is there a generator can i use for that?

Comment: Are you familiar with the openpyxl module for Python? You could use that

Comment: thanks but unfortunately not

Comment: You'll find this helpful: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 0):

THe following creates 16 columns of Hex colour codes, including all possible codes.  I tried to change each cell to the corresponding colour but there seems to be an excel limit on how many different colours you can use in a worksheet; so I have included a bit of code that converts whichever cell you select into that cell's colour.  Not sure if either of these are what you wanted but hopefully they help.

```
Private l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, lNum, lRow, lHexLong As Long
Private l1stDigit, l2ndDigit, l3rdDigit, l4thDigit, l5thDigit, l6thDigit, lDigit, lHex As String

    Sub mHex()
    
    For l1 = 1 To 16
        lRow = 1
        lNum = l1
        fBase16
        l1stDigit = lDigit
        For l2 = 1 To 16
            lNum = l2
            fBase16
            l2ndDigit = lDigit
            For l3 = 1 To 16
                lNum = l3
                fBase16
                l3rdDigit = lDigit
                For l4 = 1 To 16
                    lNum = l4
                    fBase16
                    l4thDigit = lDigit
                    For l5 = 1 To 16
                        lNum = l5
                        fBase16
                        l5thDigit = lDigit
                        For l6 = 1 To 16
                            lNum = l6
                            fBase16
                            l6thDigit = lDigit
                            lHex = "#" & l1stDigit & l2ndDigit & l3rdDigit & l4thDigit & l5thDigit & l6thDigit
                            Cells(lRow, l1).Value = lHex
                            lRow = lRow + 1
                        Next
                    Next
                Next
            Next
            MsgBox (Time())
        Next
    Next
            
    End Sub
    Sub CellColour()
    lHex = ActiveCell.Value
    lHexLong = Application.WorksheetFunction.Hex2Dec(Mid(lHex, 6, 2) & Mid(lHex, 4, 2) & Mid(lHex, 2, 2))
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = lHexLong
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
     End With
    End Sub
    Function fBase16()
    Select Case lNum
            Case 1
            lDigit = "0"
            Case 2
            lDigit = "1"
            Case 3
            lDigit = "2"
            Case 4
            lDigit = "3"
            Case 5
            lDigit = "4"
            Case 6
            lDigit = "5"
            Case 7
            lDigit = "6"
            Case 8
            lDigit = "7"
            Case 9
            lDigit = "8"
            Case 10
            lDigit = "9"
            Case 11
            lDigit = "A"
            Case 12
            lDigit = "B"
            Case 13
            lDigit = "C"
            Case 14
            lDigit = "D"
            Case 15
            lDigit = "E"
            Case 16
            lDigit = "F"
            End Select
    End Function
```

Comment: Just curious, what language is this? And how would one run this code?

Comment: thank you so much how can I export all this combination to excel?

Comment: I'd filtered on questions with an Excel tag and hadn't spotted the Python tag.  This is VBA and runs from within Excel. You just need to copy it into a macro.  Easiest way is to recordd a macro and stop it without doing anything, then step into the macro and paste the code in over the existing code.  You will then be able to run it.  It takes 15-20 mins to run completely.

Answer (score 0):

This formula in Excel365 will give you 16.772.216 million HEX-Codes in
16 columns and 1.048.264 rows

```
=DEC2HEX(SEQUENCE(1048264;16))
```

Excel will calculate a moment ;-)

Comment: thanks, bro but this not working for me I get this message " Excel ran out of resources while attempting to calculate one or more formulas. as a result, these formulas cannot be evaluated

Comment: @mrtoast Seems you need a little bit more memory ;-) .. You could try to split it in more Formulas with less coulums. Maybe:  DEC2HEX(SEQUENCE(1048264;8)) and  DEC2HEX(SEQUENCE(1048264; 8; 8386113))

Comment: not working :( is that working for you?

Comment: @mrtoast yes,, is working without problems

Comment: maybe this problem with my pc ty man!